# How to clone Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from HDD to SSD?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, cloning, migration

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed on a 1000 GB HDD `/dev/sda` (93% free space) on my laptop:

```
/dev/sda1 -> 512M   - vfat        - EFI System Partition
/dev/sda2 -> 732M   - ext4        - Linux File System (
/dev/sda3 -> 930.3G - crypto_LUKS - Linux File System (empty)
```

I would like to use a 120 GB SSD (not yet installed) for the OS on this laptop now. The old HDD should be simply used as an additional partition for file storage afterwards; no dual boot required. Instead of having to re-install Ubuntu again on the SSD, I am looking for a way to clone my existing system installation from HDD to the new SSD.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Create partitions, copy files, update boot manager.

Comment: Is sda2 is your `/` filesystem? Do you need to clone sda3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option a)

- install fresh and copy over your personal files / restore installed packages

option b)

- save your disk encryption key from the old install
- boot from CD/USB (I would use ubuntu install media, because there you can install all missing tools)
- clone partition 1 and 2
- create partion 3 new with cryptsetup/zuluCrypt using the old key
- mount both encrypted partitions
- clone files from sda3 to the new disk using rsync.

Comment: This doesn't work... It boots into the old install location

Comment: on option b) you must fix all entrys from fstab and also crypttab and run update-grub and update-initramfs again.